# How to plan database for products with different update frequencies

Tags: database-design

We are building an e-commerce site. We have 10-50 products to sell but our users may sell their own stuff too. And it is required that all our own products and our users products would go from the same purchase process for buyers.

I have the question that our products has unlimited stock but users products would probably have limits.

So the question is how can i relieve myself from the pain of storing all these products to the same table.
I mean, user may have a product with stock quantity of 1 and this product record will be useless after 1 sale.

Here is a breif description of my design till now

**Addresses**(AddressId[PK]) < **Orders**(OrderId[PK], AddressId[FK]) < **OrderLines**(OrderLineId[PK], OrderId[FK], ProductId[FK]) > **Products**(ProductId[PK]) < **ProductPrices**(ProductPriceId[PK], CurrencyId[FK], ProductId[FK]) > **Currencies**(CurrencyId[PK])

Products may have multiple prices according to where they are being sold.

So should i divide products table for different purposes. Like for example;

- SecondHandProducts,
- < SiteName >Products,
- CorporateProducts.

(If so how can i achieve this?)

So the growing secondhandproducts table will not effect my Core Products table(< SiteName >Products).

Or am i overthinking this and should just store all the products to same table.

PS. There is not any difference between these product products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, as you say, there is no difference between the products there is no need to model them separately. Have one Product table which will contain ALL your products, but have a separate table called ProductCategory which will tell what type of Product you have in the Product table. I would model this as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
    ProductId int PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductCategoryId int, //FK

    // Other product attributes
)

CREATE TABLE ProductCategory
(
    ProductCategoryId int PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductType,  <choose your own data type>
    ProductCategoryDescription, <choose type>
    // Other product category attributes
)
```

Comment: Yes but isn't the large number of rows of second hand products will reduce the query times for my main products unnecessarily? We wont be creating too many main products and we expect high number of other products. so when i try to query something about main products wouldnt it be faster if the other produts would be seperated ?

Comment: Not really. If you have a category called 'Main' for example and you have an index on Products on the ProductCategoryId column then you will get your results back in the most optimal way.